# What could be causing an unexpected_EOF error with libbzip2 readOpen function?

Tags: compression, bzip2, libzip

I'm following the bzip2 programming with libbzip2 instructions to make a script for compression/decompression, but I have run into issues with the reading step. Here's my code:

```
int decode = (argv[4][0]=='d');
 FILE* f = fopen( argv[2], "rb" ); if( f==0 ) return 2;
 FILE* g = fopen( argv[3], "wb" ); if( g==0 ) return 2;
 int bzError;
 int nBuf;
 int f_len = flen(f);
 byte* inp = new byte[f_len*4+1024*1024];   if( inp==0 ) return 3;

 
 f_len = fread( inp, 1,f_len, f );
 
 if( decode==0 ) {
   int BLOCK_MULTIPLIER = atoi( argv[5] );
   BZFILE *myBZ = BZ2_bzWriteOpen(&bzError, g, BLOCK_MULTIPLIER, 0, 0);
   BZ2_bzWrite(&bzError, myBZ, inp, f_len);
   BZ2_bzWriteClose(&bzError, myBZ, 0, NULL, NULL);
   
  } else {
   byte buf[4096];
   
   BZFILE *myBZ = BZ2_bzReadOpen(&bzError, f, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
   if (bzError != BZ_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "E: BZ2_bzReadOpen: %d\n", bzError);
      return -1;
   }

   while (bzError == BZ_OK) {
      int nread = BZ2_bzRead(&bzError, myBZ, buf, sizeof buf);
      cout<<"nread= "<<nread<<"\n";
      if (bzError == BZ_OK || bzError == BZ_STREAM_END) {
         size_t nwritten = fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
         if (nwritten != (size_t) nread) {
            fprintf(stderr, "E: short write\n");
            return -1;
  }
}
```

}

```
   if (bzError != BZ_STREAM_END) {
      fprintf(stderr, "E: bzip error after read: %d\n", bzError);
      return -1;
```

}

```
   BZ2_bzReadClose(&bzError, myBZ);
   return 0;
```

}

The compression mode works fine, but if it is in decompression mode, the bzRead step fails and I get the following output from my error messages/statements:

nread = 0
E: bzip error after read: -7

Why would nread be 0? Also, the -7 represents an unexpected EOF, but how is that possible? I have tried running this on files compressed with the built in linux bzip2 as well, and gotten the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're reading the entire input file before you decide if you're decoding or not. If you are, then you try to continue reading that same input file even though you had already reached the end of the file. So you get nothing.

Comment: Oh wow I'm dumb haha. I created that buffer to get the length of my file for the encoder, but didnt see this side effect coming. Thanks!